# Unable to build shaderc with new experimental gradle plugin android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I am trying to build shaderc from NDK 12's third party folder. It build properly with "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3" but gives following error for "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8+"

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
C:/SDKL/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/third_party/Android.mk:124: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':framework:generateJsonModelRelease'.
Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\SDKL\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\GVRVV\GVRf\Framework\framework\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\GVRVV\GVRf\Framework\framework\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=C:\GVRVV\GVRf\tools\Framework\framework.externalNativeBuild\ndkBuild\release\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\GVRVV\GVRf\tools\Framework\framework\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib -j4 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

C:/SDKL/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/third_party/Android.mk:124: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

Link: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/shader-compilers.html

Comment: First thing to try would be checking NDK r13 beta 2 to see if the problem is resolved. shaderc has received a number of updates since r12, so this may have just been a bug that was fixed.

Comment: @DanAlbert Tried with ndk r13 beta 2. Still the same error

Comment: For anyone else landing here, it's possible this is related to http://b.android.com/222601

Comment: if you could use cmake to do it, this one could do the same thing:  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials/tree/master/tutorial03_traceable_layers; before trying to import it into android studio, DO change def USE_CMAKE = 1 [it is default to 0 ] in layerlib\build.gradle